# I can't run dash plotly map

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash

I am learning how to use dash and plotly in my projetcs. Im triyng to run the exemple code below:

```
import dash

app = dash.Dash()

app.layout = html.Div(
html.H1(children="Hello000")
)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

But this keeps happening:

```
Dash is running on http://127.0.0.1:8050/

 * Serving Flask app '__main__' (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: on
An exception has occurred, use %tb to see the full traceback.

SystemExit: 1
```

And it appears a "x" on the code cell, so the code didn't work. The channel "http://127.0.0.1:8050/" keeps loading forever, also nothing happens.

Can you help me?

Comment: Are you importing html? `from dash import html`

Comment: It says `use %tb to see the full traceback.` Have you done that? It will explain your error. Like @r-beginners said, I expect it's an import error.

Comment: I already imported html from dash, but I don't know how to use "%tb"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It happened to me with Jupyter notebook. You should turn off the automatic reloading `use_reloader=False`, if the `debug = True`:

```
import dash
from dash import html


app = dash.Dash()

app.layout = html.Div(
html.H1("Hello000")
)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True,use_reloader=False)
```

In the [documentation](https://dash.plotly.com/devtools):

> For example, to turn off the automatic reloader but keep the rest of
> the development features, you could run:
>
> app.run_server(debug=True, use_reloader=False)